# How do I get mean intensity of TIFF files in a tibble?

Tags: r, tiff, tibble

I am using the following code to get TIFF files into R for analysis:

```
library(magick)

tiffiles<-list.files("C:/Users/folder_with_multiple_tifs/", pattern = "*.tif", full.names=TRUE)


importedtifs<-c()

for(file in tiffiles) {importedtifs<-append(importedtifs, image_read(file))}
importedtifs
```

This gives me a tibble with each row corresponding to a TIFF file.  I can then use `mean(as.integer(importedtifs[[1]]))` to get the average pixel intensity of the first TIFF. It is a small positive number for the images I am working with.

I would like to have a single command that returns the mean pixel intensity of each individual TIFF in the tibble.  When I try `lapply(importedtifs, function(x) mean(as.integer(x)))`, I get a large negative number, which is not the pixel intensity.

Is there a way to do this? I don't understand exactly how the tibble is storing the data for each TIFF.

Comment: You need this instead: `lapply(importedtifs, function(x)mean(as.integer(x[[1]])))`

Answer (score 0):

DaveArmstrong's solution works.  The variation below delivers the means in a list that can be manipulated downstream:

```
means<-c()
for(i in 1:length(importedtifs)){
  means<-c(means, mean(as.integer(importedtifs[[i]])))
}
```